# Is there an extension for Active Directory authentication for CakePHP 4.X?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, ldap, migration, cakephp-4.x

I've been requested to start porting our internal tools to CakePHP 4 (from a variety of CakePHP 2.X and 3.X).  One of the items on my checklist that is missing is a library to enable authentication against an MS Active directory.

I am currently using thefollowing  CakePHP 3 extension
https://github.com/unholyknight/active-directory-authenticate
Unfortunately, this extension doesn't use the new Authentication middleware found in CakePHP 4.

I was wondering if anybody has seen or used an extension or library of some sort that would provide AD authentication for CakePHP 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such 3rd party plugin, but it might of course exist, however Stackoverflow is not the right place for such questions, you're better off asking stuff like this on [**Slack**](https://cakesf.herokuapp.com/) or the [**forums**](https://discourse.cakephp.org/).

That being said, CakePHP's authentication plugin ships with a basic [**LDAP identifier**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html#ldap).

```php
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Ldap', [
    'host' => 'ldap.example.com',
    'port' => 389,
    'bindDN' => function ($username) {
        // validate $username here before embedding it in the DN string!

        return "cn=$username,ou=unit,dc=example,dc=com";
    },
    'ldap' => \Authentication\Identifier\Ldap\ExtensionAdapter::class,
    'options' => [
        \LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION => 3,
    ],
]);
```

Identifiers are pretty basic stuff, in case the built-in one doesn't suit your needs, it should be rather simple to port the [**`unholyknight/active-directory-authenticate` LDAP authenticator**](https://github.com/unholyknight/active-directory-authenticate/blob/master/src/Auth/AdldapAuthenticate.php) to an [**LDAP identifier**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/2.3.0/src/Identifier/LdapIdentifier.php).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  LDAP identifier might be enough to jury rig what I need without a third party extension.